# UPDATE Statistics with full scan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Does running UPDATE Statistics on SQL 2008 r2 with full scan on a large table 50 million rows (non partitioned)? I am trying to confirm the following behavior.

a) takes any locks during the entire run? Not sure but I think no locks are taken however a sr. dba told me that it takes schema modify lock (hmm...)

b) cause blocking -- I don't think so

c) cause heavy IO -- as each and every page will be read into the memory and pollute the data page buffer cache. So generally you should do this off hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a) Pretty much anything takes a schema stability lock. You don't want something else changing the structure of the table while you are updating your statistics. According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195565), update statistics takes schema stability and modification locks.

b) If something tries to change the table's structure, it will be blocked. IIRC, update stats does dirty reads, so it shouldn't block connections that are merely reading or writing.

c) If you use FULLSCAN, it will read the entire table because that is what you told it to do. I don't see how that can be seen as anything but 'causing heavy i/o'. Normally the default of 'sampling' works well enough, but I have seen it cause problems with data with non-homogenous distributions. Often, it's also easier to just reindex the whole table (especially if you can do it online) because reindexing is parallelizable where as update statistics isn't. (AFAIK, MS did not fix that in sql 2008.)