# Should I use UPDATE STATISTICS option?

Tags: sql-server

I am not a guru of SQL Server, I'm just studying it, and I have the following question:

Should I use UPDATE STATISTICS option?

I want to know something from your experience is it good practice and it is better to do it on a regular basis or it is better don't even touch it?

Comment: Article contain pretty good stuff to know about statistic https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-statistics-questions-we-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: Which update statistics option are you referring to (auto create, auto update, async update)?  There are valid use cases to use, or not use, each of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on my personal experience the answer is *it depends*

yes - 
When you're not getting acceptable query response times from a properly indexed table, or tables that get a huge number of inserts/updates/deletes

[image]

if you have been monitoring query performance, or stored procedures performance, and the estimates do not match the real values
but you [need to be careful with a few things](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/update-statistics-with-full-scan?rq=1) when using fullscan

if you keep the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS and AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS both set to ON
and use update stats with percentage 
and take good care of your indexes ([when you rebuild an index it automatically update the stats for that index](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-10-rebuilding-indexes-and-updating-statistics/))

> The following example [updates the statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) for all indexes on the
>   SalesOrderDetail table.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
UPDATE STATISTICS Sales.SalesOrderDetail;
GO
```

there is another good article about [UPDATE STATISTICS: the Secret IO Explosion](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/update-statistics-the-secret-io-explosion/)

and this one: [SQL SERVER STATISTICS: MAINTENANCE AND BEST PRACTICES](https://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-server-statistics-maintenance-and-best-practices/)
where the author mentions examples and situations.